# Why cannot I save a modal using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium WebDriver (with Java) to work on a web page. It needs to :

1. click on a link
2. that opens a modal
3. fill a textbox
4. save the modal

I am able to achieve till 3. Also, I am able to click on the save button. But After clicking on Save, the saving just keeps on loading.

Expected behaviour: It should get saved successfully and the modal should go away.

Actual behaviour: Its just saving endlessly!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOueA.png)

I am not sure what piece of code to provide here because as far as the code is concerned its doing what it should. Its only after clicking on the Save button that its not doing what it should.

Comment: "as far as the code is concerned its doing what it should" --> mmm, from the description it seems that not really. You should show your implementation, then someone for sure will be able to help.

Comment: The picture you have provided shows no value for the chosen file path. Are you sure you set the filepath correctly? Does it work manually? What if you break right before clicking Save and then set the file manually, does it work when the script clicks Save?

Comment: You really need to post some code. You can post the few lines leading up to the one that is having the issue. There may be something you have overlooked that someone here might catch that is causing the problem. Also add a tag for the language you are using.